# Why would ipconfig /release then /renew "fix" an apparent DNS client issue

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, windows-7

I seem to be having DNS issues --- which I suspect may be client related.  At seemly random intervals, name resolution of local FQDN names fails.

There's a warning in the system log:
`Name resolution for the name xxxxxxxx.yyy.zzz timed out after none of the configured DNS servers responded.`  (name redacted)

If I do `ipconfig /release` and then `ipconfig /renew` then all is fine, until the next random occurrence.

This is a very small network, with a Windows 2008 (SP2) standard running Active Directory + DHCP + DNS.

My workstation is Windows 7 (SP1)

We're on the same physical network, with a netgear switch of some sort (not my area).

I'm at a loss on how to trouble shoot this issue --- resetting the switch didn't sort out the problem, but the release / renew did

I should also conclude by saying that it appears from the looks of ipconfig /all before and after that the settings remained the same (which is what I would expect)

Comment: Have you watch the network traffic with Wireshark already?

Comment: Run nslookup on the client & server to test DNS, post results.  Post any related event log errors on the client and server.  Are _all_ of the DNS servers in DHCP scope the internal AD DC(s)?

Answer (score 0):

I recently had a similar problem, that in the end seemed to be due to having multiple DHCP servers responding with a reasonably short lease time. The only thing that changed was the IP address, but it was enough to cause problems.

Might be worth checking whether your DHCP server has changed between 'working' and 'not working'.